# Current_user method for authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, basic-authentication

I am using `authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest` for simple administration within my app. It would be nice if the admin could see all of the `delete`, `edit` links for an object when logged in but have these hidden for regular users.

The app has no scope for users signing up or multiple users so devise or a similar authentication platform seems overkill in this instance.

I have tried to use the `authenticate` method in the view, as you would with a current_user method. However, it infinitely prompts you to login, which isn't ideal.

Is there a way to replicate the popular `current_user` method to check whether a session has been created and use this as a helper method?

application_controller.rb

```
helper_method :authenticate

USERS = { "username" => "password",
           "APP" => Digest::MD5.hexdigest(["APP", "realm", "password"].join(":"))}

private

def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest(CONFIG[:realm]) do |username|
      USERS[username]
    end
  end
```

usage in controller

```
before_action :authenticate
```

**Update**

Thanks to Peter Goldstein's answer, I was able to save the username inside the authenticate block into a `session[:admin]` variable and use this inside the current_user helper method.

Comment: Do you have a user model that corresponds to your USERS hash?  How are you determining whether a user is an admin or not?

Comment: There is no user model or table, the code has been duplicated from here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Digest.html. It's the simplest form of authentication, if the username and password are correct you get logged in.

Comment: Right - but you're saying there's a distinction between admins and non admins.  How are you determining whether a user is an admin based on their username and password? (Note: the example code you copied has no such distinction)

Comment: There's only a difference between being logged in and not. If you are logged in you can perform certain actions otherwise not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def authenticate
   current_user_name = nil
   is_authenticated = authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest(CONFIG[:realm]) do |username|
     current_user_name = username
     USERS[username]
   end
   @current_user = current_user_name if is_authenticated
   is_authenticated
end

def current_user
  @current_user
end
helper_method :current_user
```

should capture the username from the HTTP digest request and make it visible in the current_user method